# Intel Server Board: Ethernet MT connection vs PM connection

Tags: internet, connection, ethernet, intel, hardware

What's the difference between an MT ethernet connection and a PM ethernet connection? Intel server board has two ethernet ports that are named in that manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two adapters from Intel. http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/network/1000pm/ and http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/network/1000-mt

Answer (score 2):

Intel MT are PCI based NICs with the intel PRO chipset. There isn't much info on the PT cards, but it appears that they were an older model for OEMS. So I think you might have a driver mismatch, or 2 similar NICs were placed on your Board.